# How do I set the shared access policy for an Azure Queue?

Tags: security, azure, queue

Apparently access to Azure queues can be controlled using a Shared Access Policy.  The example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh508996 confirms this, but then only provides an example for a blob shared access policy.  Does anyone have any references on how the same is achieved for Queues (and Tables)?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the complete sample on the Windows Azure Storage blog: [Introducing Table SAS (Shared Access Signature), Queue SAS and update to Blob SAS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/12/introducing-table-sas-shared-access-signature-queue-sas-and-update-to-blob-sas.aspx). Here is the part that assigns the policy to a queue:

```
// Create the GC queue SAS policy.
QueuePermissions gcQueuePermissions = new QueuePermissions();
SharedAccessQueuePolicy gcQueuePolicy = new SharedAccessQueuePolicy()
{
    // Providing the max duration
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.MaxValue,
    // Permission is granted to process queue messages.
    Permissions = SharedAccessQueuePermissions.ProcessMessages
};

// Associate the above policy with a signed identifier
gcQueuePermissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Add(
    gcPolicySignedIdentifier,
    gcQueuePolicy);

// The below call will result in a Set Queue ACL request to be sent to 
// Windows Azure Storage in order to store the policy and associate it with the 
// "GCAccessPolicy" signed identifier that will be referred to
// by the generated SAS token
this.gcQueue.SetPermissions(gcQueuePermissions);
```

Comment: Great!  Thanks for super fast response...  Based on the types you included I then also found [link](http://vunvulearadu.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-use-shared-access-signature-with_11.html).  My problem now is that I my VS2012 project does not recognise these types (e.g., QueuePermissions), and I can't even locate what namespace their in on the Microsoft site.  I have the June 2012 SP1 Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2012) installed - is this 1.7.1 or do I need another download for this to work?

Comment: OK, so I guess 1.7.1 is not an official release just yet.  Anyway, I downloaded and compiled the project [here](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/sdk_1.7.1), and now I'm good to go.  Thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 0):

Does the [announcement post for table SAS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/12/introducing-table-sas-shared-access-signature-queue-sas-and-update-to-blob-sas.aspx) *(especially the SAS token producer portion of the sample)* can help you any way? It seems to me the SAS is available on Table and Queues starting with SDK 1.7.

Comment: Thanks David - it certainly does help... I'm a little embarrassed that my Googling did not find this!